# Remote Debugging With Bluemix and STS 3.7.1

Tags: ibm-cloud, spring-tool-suite

I was trying out some of the new Boot Dashboard features in STS 3.7.1 when deploying the Boot app to IBM Bluemix and most of them worked except for the remote debugging feature.  At first I thought it might be a problem with the buildpack used on Bluemix since by default Bluemix uses the Liberty buildpack.  So I switched to using the CF Java Buildpack but I still have not been able to get it working.

When I select the (Re)debug option for my app the app restarts sucessfully but in STS I get the following error
[image]

Comment: Do you mean when you clicked the "Enable Application Debug" menuitem the debug session won't start? (as described here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/eclipsetools/eclipsetools.html#remotedebug)

Comment: since the boot dashboard doesn't use the bluemix-specific debugging, there might be a different issue here. The boot dashboard uses the Spring Boot Devtools for remote debugging. Do you have the boot devtools on the classpath of the project?

Comment: @MartinLippert yes I have the devtools on the classpath, the debug functionality works fine when deployed to Pivotal CF

Comment: @Jack-JunjieCai no I am not talking about the bluemix debug tools, I am talking about the Spring functionality mentioned here http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/latest/NewAndNoteworthy.html

Comment: did you try to setup the boot devtools debugging manually (as described in the Spring Boot docs here: https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3 ? Would be interesting to see if this is a general problem running boot devtools in a bluemix environment or a specific issue with the way the boot dashboard in STS set things up.

Comment: The reload and remote update functionality seems to work fine in Bluemix if that is what you are wondering.